# Conditionally choose serializer

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-framework-gis

I have three Django models.

```
class Asset(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=255)


class Place(Asset):
  location = PointField()


class Zone(Asset):
  location = PolygonField()
```

I want to use the same endpoint for Place and Zone.
Is it possible to decide for each request which serializer will be used e.g. I could easily check if the requested Asset is a Place or a Zone?

I am only interested in handling a single instance hence there is no need to handle ListView etc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can **override the [`get_serializer_class`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#get_serializer_classself) method** in your view and add the logic for deciding the correct serializer there.

As per the [DRF docs:](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#get_serializer_classself)

> `get_serializer_class(self)`
>
> Returns the class that should be used for the serializer. Defaults to
>   returning the serializer_class attribute.
>
> May be overridden to provide dynamic behavior, such as using different
>   serializers for read and write operations, or providing different
>   serializers to different types of users.

**Code:**

```
class MyView(..):
    ...

    def get_serializer_class(self):
        if asset == place: # here add the logic to decide the asset type
             return PlaceSerializer 
        return ZoneSerializer
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer.